# heroku + wkhtmltopdf + pdfkit = error 1299?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, wkhtmltopdf

We've had PDFkit + Wkhtmltopdf running successfully at Heroku for a long time now. All of the sudden, PDFs aren't rendering. I turned 'quiet' off and looked at our logs and see this:

```
2014-09-05T18:42:17.909469+00:00 app[web.2]: Completed 200 OK in 317ms (Views: 257.1ms | ActiveRecord: 40.4ms)] 0%
Counting pages (2/6)                                               =============>                         ] 58%
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       ==============================] Object 1 of 1
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           ==============================] Object 1 of 1
2014-09-05T18:42:18.171572+00:00 app[web.2]: Printing pages (6/6)
Done                                                                                                      ] Preparing

2014-09-05T18:42:18.217154+00:00 app[web.2]: Exit with code 1 due to http error: 1299
2014-09-05T18:42:18.226795+00:00 app[web.2]:
2014-09-05T18:42:18.226801+00:00 app[web.2]: RuntimeError (command failed (exitstatus=1): /app/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64-12 --page-size Letter --margin-top 0.0in --margin-right 0.0in --margin-bottom 0.0in --margin-left 0.0in --encoding UTF-8 --print-media-type - -):
```

I can't find anywhere what "http error 1299" is...

And nothing has changed... it just happened out of the blue, in the middle of the day with no code pushes in sight. And of course it runs fine in Dev.

During debugging I updated pdfkit to 0.6.2 and I've tried both v12.0 and 11.0rc1 of wkhtmltopdf. If I run it on heroku bash, I can wkhtmltopdf-amd64 google.com google.pdf just fine without error.

Anyone else seeing this? Can someone tell me where to start?

Comment: Try to add a question into the wkhtmltopdf issues at https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues to find documentation on what is error code 1299. BTW, very often things crash when there is a 404 on the page - such as a missing image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, and the solution, though the cause and reason why it happened was unclear.

After some trial and error I discovered that the NewRelic gem, which we and others on heroku tend to use to track system performance, was injecting a javascript script that loads off of NewRelic's server.  We knew this was there, as its used for Browser measurement with New Relic.  But we totally forgot that it also would come out on the pages we're creating PDFs for because it gets injected at the Rack level I believe.

I couldn't find a way to tell it not to measure certain pages, so I just turned off browser measurement in our NewRelic.yml file.  Boom. Problem gone.  My guess is that the JS was taking too long to load in, or was causing Wkhtmltopdf to error out.

I reported it to Heroku, with the solution, in the hopes that they figure it out or talk to NewRelic if others see it.  Browser measurement is definitely not as important as PDF generation in our solution, so we can live without it.

You can see this issue at PDFkit if you want more detail.  https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/issues/251